# c++ std::copy input iterator (pointers) to vector

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, copy, std

Hi I'm trying to understand why the following code does not work. I'm trying to use pointers as the input iterator type to the std::copy algorithm. fsRead.Buffer points to the beginning of the data I want to copy, and fsRead.BufferSize is size of the data that we want to copy.

```
// AllocateZeroPool(UINT64) takes an input size, and returns a pointer to allocated memory. (this is the existing C api)
fsRead.Buffer = static_cast<UINT8*>(AllocateZeroPool(fsRead.BufferSize));
//
// this next line populates the data into fsRead.Buffer
auto status = mFs->read_data(nullptr, &fsRead);

the type of file.data is: std::vector<UINT8>
std::copy(fsRead.Buffer, fsRead.Buffer + fsRead.BufferSize, file.data.begin());
```

file.data.size() is zero with the above std::copy() call.

To get the data into the vector file.data, I currently do the copy by hand:

```
for(auto i(0U); i < fsRead.BufferSize; ++i) {
    file.mBinaryData.emplace_back(fsRead.Buffer[i]);
}
```

Why does using two pointers as input iterators not seem to work?

edit: To clarify I mean that no data is actually copied into the file.mBinaryData vector.

Comment: What does it mean that it doesn't "seem to work"? Describe the error, please...

Answer (score 4):

With `std::vector` you must use a [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter). Without it the iterator will not do a `push_back` to copy the data, but just increment the given iterator.

```
std::copy(fsRead.Buffer, fsRead.Buffer + fsRead.BufferSize, std::back_inserter(file.data));
```

Answer (score 3):

This fails because accessing iterators to a vector never change the size of the vector.

You can use one of the standard iterator adapters, such as `back_inserter`, to do this instead. That would look like this:

```
// Looks like you really wanted copy_n instead...
std::copy_n(fsRead.Buffer, fsRead.BufferSize, std::back_inserter(file.data));
```

Comment: can you elaborate on the first point you made?

"This fails because accessing iterators to a vector never change the size of the vector."

Comment: @Short: Its exactly what Olaf said in his answer -- `copy` just does `destination++`. Incrementing the value returned by `begin()` on an empty `vector` results in undefined behavior, not a bigger vector.